# Tikz library `external` produces error if package `optional` is loaded?

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive, ubuntu

I'm working on a large document which exceeded  the memory capacity of TexLive 2011 so I tried to externalize the tikz images by using it's `external` library, as described in pgfmanual. I compiled using

```
pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex
```

which resulted in an error like this:

> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape
>   -halt-on-e rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "foo-figure0" "\def\tikzexternal realjob{foo}\input{foo}"' did
>   NOT result in a usable output  file 'foo-figure0' (expected
>   one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please v erify that you have enabled
>   system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shel l-escape'.
>   Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or may
>   be the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in
>   'ktikztemplate-fig ure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset
>   the picture.

I managed to narrow down the problem and came up with the following MWE which produces the same error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{optional} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(0,0)--(1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment out the `\usepackage{optional}` line and the error is gone. I could somewhat easily manage without that package, but it would be nice if there is some solution for this.

I use TexLive 2011 on Ubuntu 11.10 (both freshly installed few day ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that if you provide some option the the `\usepackage{optional}` command this compiles.

```
\usepackage[opta]{optional}
```

This is just a guess, but I think what is happening is that since you did not provide a package option, it reverts to going to the command line to ask the user to input the option. But since you are running in batch mode this is a problem.

The following code works for me using `pdflatex` with TeXLive2011:

```
\ifdefined\Options%
\else%
    \def\Options{opta}
\fi%

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[\Options]{optional} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
  \opt{opta}{Option A was selected}
  \opt{optb}{Option B was selected}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(0,0)--(1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and yields:

[image]

Comment: I just tried your proposal (adding `[opta]` as an option, but _it does not compile and I end up with the same error_. I also run again the compilation command from the terminal (after i reverted back to `\usepackage{optional}` and it indeed asked for an option. I entered random string as an option at the error occurred again. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have included the full code example, so try that. Also, you mention you did a fresh install, but did you also do an update to get the latest packages? I updated everything a few weeks ago (using TeXLive2011 on Mac OS)

Comment: Yes, I have also updated TexLive2011 (`sudo tlmgr update --self --all). I tried your code and it compile just fine (using `pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex`). Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: So it compiles now with or without this extra if else ?